# Getting a variable from url in Flask to use outside a function

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner at programming, so I hope I can get some help here.

My question:
I got this code:

```
import os, json, subprocess, sys
import CallExternalServiceConfig as c
from flask import Flask, jsonify

DATAS = "datas"
SOURCE_FOLDER = "source_folder"
NAME_SCRIPT = "name_script"
PARAMETERS = "parameters"

with open("CallScript.json", "r") as read_file:
data = json.load(read_file)

for trigger in data[DATAS]:
adress=trigger[SOURCE_FOLDER]
namescript=trigger[NAME_SCRIPT]
parameter=trigger[PARAMETERS]

app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/Test/<string:jsonname>/')

def action():
    #try:
    subprocess.call([adress+namescript, parameter.split(",")], shell=True)
    print(parameter.split(","))
    return jsonify(adress+namescript)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=c.get(c.SERVER_HOST, '127.0.0.1'), port=int(c.get(c.SERVER_PORT, 
    '5000')));
```

and i want to take the `jsonname` string from the url and use it to replace the `"CallScript.json"` so its dynamic. But I have no idea how I can access that variable outside the `def action()` function.

I'm using Flask

Comment: this may help you, ```json_name = request.args.get('jsonname', default = '', type = str)```

Comment: inside ```def action():```

Comment: Thanks gonna try that

Comment: Sorry for the amount of comments but now that this doesnt give me an error anymore, how can I use that now to replace the "CallScript.json"? Since atm it does not find the variable

Comment: I am unable to put it in comments. I will write separate answer

Comment: It is still using the default json and not the one from the url

Comment: Also it gives me an error if I try def action(): I have to def action(jsonname):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os, json, subprocess, sys
import CallExternalServiceConfig as c
from flask import Flask, jsonify

DATAS = "datas"
SOURCE_FOLDER = "source_folder"
NAME_SCRIPT = "name_script"
PARAMETERS = "parameters"


app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/Test/<string:jsonname>/')

def action():
    json_name = request.args.get('jsonname', default = '', type = str)
    with open(json_name + ".json", "r") as read_file:
        data = json.load(read_file)
    for trigger in data[DATAS]:
        adress=trigger[SOURCE_FOLDER]
        namescript=trigger[NAME_SCRIPT]
        parameter=trigger[PARAMETERS]

    subprocess.call([adress+namescript, parameter.split(",")], shell=True)
    print(parameter.split(","))
    return jsonify(adress+namescript)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=c.get(c.SERVER_HOST, '127.0.0.1'), port=int(c.get(c.SERVER_PORT, 
    '5000')));
```

Comment: you answer contains only code. Could you also add some description of what this code is doing and how it relates to the original question?

Comment: This seems to almost work only got an error at "for trigger in dada[DATAS]: since it does not know which data to use (atleast thats my guess)

Comment: had to replace default = ' ' with default = jsonname but now it does work thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First, we initialize the variables you want to be able to access outside the function. Then, when the URL is called, we pass the json filed name to a function that will reset those parameters to the values from that json file.

```
adress = ""
namescript = ""
parameter = ""

def read_json(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as read_file:
        data = json.load(read_file)
    for trigger in data[DATAS]:
        adress=trigger[SOURCE_FOLDER]
        namescript=trigger[NAME_SCRIPT]
        parameter=trigger[PARAMETERS]

@app.route('/Test/<string:jsonname>/')
def action():
    json_name = request.args.get('jsonname', default = '', type = str) + ".json"
    read_json(json_name)
```

When your route gets called, `json_name` will now be set to whatever the parameter in the URL was.

Comment: It is still using the default json and not the one from the url

Comment: Also it gives me an error if I try def action(): I have to def action(jsonname):

Comment: Oh I see, you want to load that JSON when that URL is called. You just have to change where you load the JSON (see edited answer).